# Why does this code not work properly?

Tags: java, runtime-error

This part is supposed to add a train to the TRAININFO table in my database. I have to use mysql.

So there are some constraints I have to see before adding the train.

1. `jTextField1.getText()`; TrainNo. should not have more than 6 characters and it should be an integer.
2. `jTextField2.getText()`; TrainName. Should not have more than 30 characters.
3. `jTextField10,jTextField12` have Depttime and araivaltime respectively.
   It has 5 characters,"hr:mn" So I have to check if 'hr'<=24 and 'mn'<=59.
4. If the value of `jTextField3.getText()==0` (number of ac1 coaches), then the trainfare for ac1 coaches (tfac1) should also be ==0.

Keeping this in mind I have tried to code it. but it doesn't work.

when ever i run this there is an error  message .

Please do tell me where I am wrong.

**stacktrace:[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@e596c9**

okay heres how it should work:

```
String m="-",t="-",w="-",th="--",f="-",st="--",s="-",runson;
if(jCheckBox1.isSelected()==true)
{
  m="m";
}

if(jCheckBox2.isSelected()==true)
{
  t="t";
}

if(jCheckBox3.isSelected()==true)
{
  w="w";
}

if(jCheckBox4.isSelected()==true)
{
  th="th";
}

if(jCheckBox5.isSelected()==true)
{
  f="f";
}

if(jCheckBox6.isSelected()==true)
{
  st="st";
}

if(jCheckBox7.isSelected()==true)
{
  s="s";
}

runson=m+t+w+th+f+st+s;

int h1=Integer.valueOf(jTextField10.getText().substring(0,2));

int mins1=Integer.valueOf(jTextField10.getText().substring(3,5));

int h2=Integer.valueOf(jTextField12.getText().substring(0,2));

int mins2=Integer.valueOf(jTextField12.getText().substring(2,3));

String time1=jTextField10.getText().substring(0,2)+jTextField10.getText().substring

(2,3)+jTextField10.getText().substring(3,5);

String time2=jTextField12.getText().substring(0,2)+jTextField12.getText().substring

(2,3)+jTextField12.getText().substring(3,5);

String tfac1=jTextField13.getText();

String tfac2=jTextField14.getText();

String  tfac3=jTextField15.getText();

String tfsl=jTextField16.getText();

if(Integer.valueOf(jTextField3.getText())==0)

{
  tfac1="0";

}
if(Integer.valueOf(jTextField4.getText())==0)
{
  tfac2="0";
}
if(Integer.valueOf(jTextField5.getText())==0)
{
  tfac3="0";
}
if(Integer.valueOf(jTextField6.getText())==0)
{
  tfsl="0";
}
try
{
  Class.forName("java.sql.DriverManager");

Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/bvdb","root","enter");

Statement stm=con.createStatement();

   int n=jTextField1.getText().trim().length();   
int m=jTextField2.getText().trim().length();

if( n<=6 && m<=30 && h1<=24 && h2<=24 && mins1<=59 && mins2<=59 )

//This should check the constraints(1,2,3).if the condition is true the following statement will be executed ..else the catch block should be executed. But this doesn't seem to happen when i run the code. There is always an Exception raised.//

{

String q="INSERT INTO TRAININFO VALUE ("+jTextField1.getText()+",'"+jTextField2.getText()+"','"+jTextField9.getText()+"','"+time1+"','"+jTextField11.getText()+"','"+time2+"','"+runson+"',"+tfac1+","+tfac2+ ","+tfac3+","+tfsl+","+jTextField3.getText()+","+jTextField4.getText()+","+jTextField5.getText()+","+jTextField6.getText()+")";

stm.executeUpdate(q);

System.out.print("ADDED");

  }


    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Enter valid details");

}
```

Comment: please take time to format your code!

Comment: Please learn about loops , before proceeding furthur.

Comment: Please include your stack trace in your question. Read your own question back to yourself and note how it doesn't actually describe what is going wrong... We need more information before we can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`s` will always be `-` if `!jCheckBox7.isSelected()`. Think about it, you have:

```
if(something) {
   ...
} else {
   s = ...;
}
if(something2) {
   ...
} else {
   s = ...;
}
...
if(somethingN) {
   ...
} else {
   s = "-";  //This will always be executed if !somethingN
}
```

You might want to have `if.. else if` instead of `if` below `if`.

Also note that it's not a good practice to compare `boolean` by writing `== true`. This might lead to problems if you, for example, write `=` instead of `==`. Just write `if(isTrue())` instead of `if(isTrue() == true)`.

Answer (score -1):

Basically you need to split your code into many functions. That will make it more readable.

Below is an example of how to structure your code, not a complete working code.

```
public void InsertTrainInfo() {

    String runson = GetRunSon();
    Boolean validTime1 = IsTimeValid(jTextField10.getText());
    Boolean validTime2 = IsTimeValid(jTextField12.getText());
    String time1 = GetTheTime(jTextField10.getText());
    String time2 = GetTheTime(jTextField12.getText());

    String tfac1 = GetFact(jTextField13.getText());
    String tfac2 = GetFact(jTextField14.getText());
    String tfac3 = GetFact(jTextField15.getText());
    String tfsl = GetFact(jTextField16.getText());

    try {
        Class.forName("java.sql.DriverManager");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/bvdb", "root", "enter");
        Statement stm = con.createStatement();

        if (jTextField1.getText().trim().length() <= 6 && jTextField2.getText().trim().length() <= 30 && validTime1 && validTime2) {
            String q = "INSERT INTO TRAININFO VALUE (" + jTextField1.getText() + ",'" + jTextField2.getText() + "','" + jTextField9.getText() + "','" + time1 + "','" + jTextField11.getText() + "','" + time2 + "','" + runson + "'," + tfac1 + "," + tfac2 + "," + tfac3 + "," + tfsl + "," + jTextField3.getText() + "," + jTextField4.getText() + "," + jTextField5.getText() + "," + jTextField6.getText() + ")";
            stm.executeUpdate(q);

            ResetFOrm();
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        GetValidDetails();
    }
}

Boolean IsTimeValid(String timetext) {
    Boolean isOK = false;
    try {
        int h1 = Integer.valueOf(timetext.substring(0, 2));
        int mins1 = Integer.valueOf(timetext.substring(3, 5));
        isOK = (h1 <= 24 && mins1 <= 59);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        isOK = false;
    }
    return isOK;
}

String GetTheTime(String timetext) {
    // do some basic length checks
    return timetext.substring(0, 2) + timetext.substring(2, 3) + timetext.substring(3, 5);
}

String GetFact(String facttext) {
    String fact = facttext;
    if (Integer.valueOf(fact) == 0) {
        fact = "0";
    }
    return fact;
}

void ResetFOrm() {
    jTextField1.setEditable(true);
    jButton1.setEnabled(true);
    jButton2.setEnabled(false);
    jButton4.setEnabled(false);
    jTextField2.setEditable(false);
    jTextField9.setEditable(false);
    jTextField10.setEditable(false);
    jTextField11.setEditable(false);
    jTextField12.setEditable(false);
    jTextField13.setEditable(false);
    jTextField14.setEditable(false);
    jTextField15.setEditable(false);
    jTextField16.setEditable(false);
    jTextField3.setEditable(false);
    jTextField4.setEditable(false);
    jTextField5.setEditable(false);
    jTextField6.setEditable(false);
    jCheckBox1.setEnabled(false);
    jCheckBox2.setEnabled(false);
    jCheckBox3.setEnabled(false);
    jCheckBox4.setEnabled(false);
    jCheckBox5.setEnabled(false);
    jCheckBox6.setEnabled(false);
    jCheckBox7.setEnabled(false);
    jTextField1.setText("");
    jTextField2.setText("");
    jTextField3.setText("");
    jTextField4.setText("");
    jTextField5.setText("");
    jTextField6.setText("");
    jTextField7.setText("");
    jTextField8.setText("");
    jTextField9.setText("");
    jTextField10.setText("");
    jTextField11.setText("");
    jTextField12.setText("");
    jTextField13.setText("");
    jTextField14.setText("");
    jTextField15.setText("");
    jTextField16.setText("");


}

void GetValidDetails() {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Enter valid details");
    jTextField9.setEditable(true);
    jTextField10.setEditable(true);
    jTextField11.setEditable(true);
    jTextField12.setEditable(true);
    jTextField13.setEditable(true);
    jTextField14.setEditable(true);
    jTextField15.setEditable(true);
    jTextField16.setEditable(true);
    jTextField2.setEditable(true);
    jTextField3.setEditable(true);
    jTextField4.setEditable(true);
    jTextField5.setEditable(true);
    jTextField6.setEditable(true);
    jCheckBox1.setEnabled(true);
    jCheckBox2.setEnabled(true);
    jCheckBox3.setEnabled(true);
    jCheckBox4.setEnabled(true);
    jCheckBox5.setEnabled(true);
    jCheckBox6.setEnabled(true);
    jCheckBox7.setEnabled(true);
    jTextField2.setText("");
    jTextField3.setText("");
    jTextField4.setText("");
    jTextField5.setText("");
    jTextField6.setText("");
    jTextField7.setText("");
    jTextField8.setText("");
    jTextField9.setText("");
    jTextField10.setText("");
    jTextField11.setText("");
    jTextField12.setText("");
    jTextField13.setText("");
    jTextField14.setText("");
    jTextField15.setText("");
    jTextField16.setText("");
    jCheckBox1.setSelected(false);
    jCheckBox2.setSelected(false);
    jCheckBox3.setSelected(false);
    jCheckBox4.setSelected(false);
    jCheckBox5.setSelected(false);
    jCheckBox6.setSelected(false);
    jCheckBox7.setSelected(false);


}

String GetRunSon() {
    String m = "-", t = "-", w = "-", th = "--", f = "-", st = "--", s = "-", runson;
    if (jCheckBox1.isSelected()) {
        m = "m";
    }

    if (jCheckBox2.isSelected()) {
        t = "t";
    }

    if (jCheckBox3.isSelected()) {
        w = "w";
    }

    if (jCheckBox4.isSelected()) {
        th = "th";
    }

    if (jCheckBox5.isSelected()) {
        f = "f";
    }

    if (jCheckBox6.isSelected()) {
        st = "st";
    }

    if (jCheckBox7.isSelected()) {
        s = "s";
    }

    runson = m + t + w + th + f + st + s;

    return runson;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question. Also (@user3090804), note that in Java you should use `camelCase` for method names, not `TitleCase` as is used in this answer.

Comment: @Duncan your comments have been an eye opener. Thank you.